# Where is the checked out repository on local?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository

I've just learned working with subversion and a few commands such as checkout and add and list etc. 
so far what I learned was that checking out a repository means creating a working copy on local so we can modify the files and then commit the changes to the real repository.
OK, so far so good, and we use the checkout command for this purpose, passing it the url to the repository. 
So, My question might look rather stupid, but... where is this working copy??
After I check out the repository, where is the working copy created, and how can I access and modify the containing files?
I'm very confused about this. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command for a checkout looks like:

```
svn checkout REPOSITORY_PATH/project/directory [optional local target directory]
```

If you perform a `svn checkout` without specifying the target local directory as the second parameter, your checked out working copy will end up in a directory named the same as the item you checked out in whatever working directory you were in when you checked it out.

So for example, if you checked out the `proj1` project from `your/repository/projects/proj1` with a command like:

```
svn checkout http://your/repository/projects/proj1
```

Your working copy would end up in `proj1`  *inside the directory you were in when you ran the command*.  So if you did this from your home directory `/home/you`, it would be: `/home/you/proj1`

```
cd /home/you/proj1
svn info
```

Under most circumstances, you should specify the local target directory to checkout the working copy:

```
# Place the working copy in /home/you/code/proj1
svn checkout http://your/repository/projects/proj1 /home/you/code/proj1
```

Comment: Thank you. Have you worked with AnkhSVN, the svn plugin for visual studio?? I can't work with that one either.

Comment: @V0R73X No - I mainly only use command line tools though I have used TortoiseSVN before.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you run the checkout command?  Unless you specify a location to hold the working copy it will checkout in the directory you run the svn checkout command.

Feel free to put the checkout command you ran.  If you used a tool or IDE, what did you use?